# How to get media devices information?

Tags: c#, nuget, mediadevices

I'm using the `MediaDevices` NuGet package to identify all the media devices connected to the computer. I'm not sure how do i get `MediaStorageInfo`, like how much space it can hold or how many space is available.

The snippet of my code:

```
var mediadevices = mediadevice.GetDevices();
MediaStorageInfo info = new MediaStorageInfo();
foreach (var device in mediadevices)
{
    ulong cap = info.Capacity
    ulong freespace = info.FreespaceInObjects;   
}
```

The manual suggested:

```
var devicess = MediaDevice.GetDevices();
using (var device = devicess.First(d => d.FriendlyName == "My Cell Phone"))
{
    device.Connect();

    // get list of available storages (SD-Card, Internal Flash, ...)
    var objects = device.FunctionalObjects(FunctionalCategory.Storage);
    MediaStorageInfo infoss = GetStorageInfo(objects.First());
    ulong size = infoss.FreeSpaceInBytes;

    device.Disconnect();
}
```

the `GetStorageInfo` seems to be missing as the error stated that can't be resolved and doesn't exist in the current contact.I'm not sure how do i pass my `MediaDevice` into `MediaStorageInfo`. Any suggestion helps. Thank you!

Comment: Did you try reading the [manual](https://github.com/Bassman2/MediaDevices/tree/master/MediaDevicesDoc)?

Comment: yes i did. the mediastorageinfo in the manual as shown in code doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Just change:

```
GetStorageInfo(objects.First());
```

to

```
device.GetStorageInfo(objects.First())
```

Than it should look like this:

```
var devicess = MediaDevice.GetDevices();
using (var device = devicess.First(d => d.FriendlyName == "My Cell Phone"))
{
    device.Connect();

    // get list of available storages (SD-Card, Internal Flash, ...)
    var objects = device.FunctionalObjects(FunctionalCategory.Storage);
    MediaStorageInfo infoss = device.GetStorageInfo(objects.First());
    ulong size = infoss.FreeSpaceInBytes;

   device.Disconnect();
}
```